# Array don't sum numbers higher than 7

Tags: php, arrays, numbers, sum

**Problem:** This is all about ranking. This rank should contain numbers from zero up to ten. However, I notice that the sum of my array that stores the values are not entering numbers higher than 07. So, it can only sums the number from 00 up to 07! I couldn't find the mistake.

**Code:**

```
<tbody>
<?php
  $scores = array(
  "Kyle"   => array("-", 04, 04, 06, 04, 05, 04, 04),
  "Bill"   => array("-", 04, 09, 04, 07, 08, 04, 10),
  "Adam"   => array("-", 04, 04, 04, 01, 04, 04, 04),
  "Johnny" => array("-", 08, 04, 10, 04, 08, 08, 04),
?>

###function to return the sum
function cmp($a, $b) {
  return array_sum($b) - array_sum($a);
}

####sort the ranking into the td
uasort($scores, "cmp");
foreach($scores as $key=>$value) {
  echo "<tr>";
  echo "<th>$key</th>";
  echo "<td class='total' align='center' valign='middle'>" . array_sum($value) . "</td>";
  for($x=0; $x<count($value); $x++) {
    echo "<td class='games tip' align='center' valign='middle'>".sprintf('%02d', $value[$x])."</td>";
  }
  echo "</tr>";
}
?>
</tbody>
```

Thank you!

Comment: Octal numbers does not have the 8 digit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Numbers beginning with `0` are treated as octal numbers, and may only contain digits from `0` to `7`. Any other digit is treated as a delimiter, not part of the number. So `08` and `09` are interpreted as `0`.

Get rid of all you leading digits:

```
  $scores = array(
  "Kyle"   => array("-", 4, 4, 6, 4, 5, 4, 4),
  "Bill"   => array("-", 4, 9, 4, 7, 8, 4, 10),
  "Adam"   => array("-", 4, 4, 4, 1, 4, 4, 4),
  "Johnny" => array("-", 8, 4, 10, 4, 8, 8, 4),
  );
```

Answer (score 0):

In PHP and many other languages, a literal number with a leading 0 is considered to be written in octal (base 8). You might have seen this in Unix file permissions, where 0755 represents 3 bytes, not the decimal number "seven hundred and fifty five".

Similar notations exist for hexadecimal (base 16) and binary (base 2); so 10 means ten, but 010 means eight, 0x10 means sixteen, and 0b10 means two.

Since there are no digits '8' & '9' in octal, values like 08 and 09 will not work usefully. Remove the leading zeros, and you should be fine.